# Who is "Sally" referred to in this joke?

Tags: american-english

I saw the following joke on Internet.

> "A man dies and goes to heaven.
>
> As he sits in a chair Jesus Christ takes a seat in front of him.
>
> The man is confused because he is also surrounded by clocks
>
> The man asks Jesus “What are all these clocks for???”
>
> Jesus replies “These are lying clocks, the more you lie, everytime you lie, the hand turns one hour ahead”
>
> The man asks “How about Mother Teresa's clock?”
>
> Jesus points it out and said “It is at 12, meaning she never told a lie”
>
> The man stares in awe and points out a clock, “Whose clock is that?”
>
> Jesus answers,“That is **Sally’s**, it is at two, meaning she told 2 lies.”
>
> The man gets curious because he can't find Donald Trump’s clock.
>
> The man finally asks “Where is Donald Trump’s clock?”
>
> Jesus calmly looks him dead in the eye and says,
>
> “It's being used as a ceiling fan in God's office”

I get the joke. My question is who specifically "Sally" is referred to in this joke? Or it is just a random person?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about understanding jokes, not understanding English

Answer (score 2):

The name has no special meaning. It could be anyone's name.

Actually, to tell the joke properly, you should use names of known people.  The first person someone with perfect integrity, like "The Dalai Lama" or "Mahatma Gandhi", and the second someone famous for almost-perfect integrity, like "George Washington", or possibly a stereotypical figure commonly known for integrity, like "the town librarian".

But this is a very old joke.  I've heard the punchline with both Bill and Hillary Clinton, with George W. Bush, with Richard Nixon, and with many other US Presidents.